# How to add failure messages to DLQ when lambda is invoked synchronously?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have structure similar to this

> *SQS -> Lambda -> DLQ*

When Lambda is invoked asynchronously like below then failure messages are getting added successfully to DLQ.

`$ aws lambda invoke --function-name my-function  --invocation-type Event --payload '{ "key": "value" }' response.json`

But when lambda gets triggered on adding new messages to SQS then on failure, messages doesn't store in DLQ.

I found that events triggered when new message published to SQS are synchronous in nature.

> Lambda polls the queue and invokes your function synchronously with an
>   event that contains queue messages.

Reference - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html.

So I want either-

1. SQS event trigger invoke lambda asynchronously

or

2. Messages gets stored in DLQ on synchronous invocation of Lambda as well.

Comment: Please checkout this answer for understanding how to add destination on failure for synchronous invocation on lambda: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63531865/8656417

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. DLQ is used not to store error messages but to store failed events, that can be handled again later.
2. CloudWatch is used to store and show logs (including errors) for Lambda and any other AWS service.
3. The idea behind SQS triggering Lambda is that in case of Lambda failure, the event will be handled again by Lambda later.
   It's the same idea as DLQ but implemented differently.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a source that invokes the lambda synchronously like SQS, DynamoDbStream or a KinesisStream, then you need to attach the DLQ to the source. Examples:

SQS

```
  MySqsQueue:
    Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
    Properties:
      QueueName: MySqsQueueName
      RedrivePolicy:
          deadLetterTargetArn: !GetAtt Dlq.Arn
          maxReceiveCount: 1000
      VisibilityTimeout: 700

  Dlq:
    Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
    Properties:
      QueueName: MySqsQueueName # Hardcoding the name to avoid the dependency loop. 
      RedriveAllowPolicy:
          redrivePermission: "byQueue"
          sourceQueueArns:
              - !Sub arn:aws:sqs:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:MySqsQueueName
      VisibilityTimeout: 700
```

DynamoDbStream:

```
  DynamoDbStreamFanoutHandler:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      ...
      Events:
        DynamoStream:
          Type: DynamoDB
          Properties:
            BatchSize: 100
            BisectBatchOnFunctionError: True
            DestinationConfig:
              OnFailure:
                Destination: !Ref DlqArn ## The DLQ config is here.
            Enabled: True
            MaximumBatchingWindowInSeconds: 10
            MaximumRecordAgeInSeconds: -1
            MaximumRetryAttempts: 100
            ParallelizationFactor: 2
            StartingPosition:  TRIM_HORIZON
            Stream: !GetAtt DynamoDbTable.StreamArn
```